# Is it possible to load data in 2 steps in jquery datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I use a jquery datatable with a sAjaxSource and want to load data in col 1, col 2, col 3, col 4 in first way because in my datasource I have a json from a sql query with an execution time around 1 minute. In the second way, I want to load data in col 5, col 6, col 7
I have to show data in the datatable as far as possible
I think of writing 2 queries for the 2 steps => 2 datasources, and load data in the datatable in 2 steps; is it possible and how? or what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Issue here is the length of the Query you're trying to run. perhaps what you need to look into is called `Pagination`

Comment: I use pagination.
I have a complex query : 4 subqueries in the query. I try to optimize it.
The execution time is 1 minute because I limit the result to 100

Answer (score 1):

How about this: http://datatables.net/usage/server-side

> Server-side processing
>
> There are times when reading data from the DOM is simply too slow or
>   unwieldy, particularly when dealing with thousands or millions of data
>   rows. To address this DataTables' server-side processing feature
>   provides a method to let all the "heavy lifting" be done by a database
>   engine on the server-side (they are after-all highly optimised for
>   exactly this kind of thing), and then have that information drawn in
>   the user's web-browser. As such you can display tables consisting of
>   millions of rows with ease.
>
> When using server-side processing, DataTables will make an XHR request
>   to the server for each draw of the information on the page (i.e. when
>   paging, sorting, filtering etc). DataTables will send a number of
>   variables to the server to allow it to perform the required
>   processing, and then return the data in the format required by
>   DataTables.

Comment: When using server-side, have I to code the paging, ordering, filtering ... in the DAO like [here](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)? (I use sql server and hibernate mapping)